# View router not working in laravel, it is compiling successfully but rendering blank page

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

Currently learning and using VueRouter for the first time in laravel. There are no errors but when I try to run the page it just appears blank. I've gone through the code and the tutorial i have been following multiple times but cannot see what is going wrong.

This is my app.js

```
require("./bootstrap");

window.Vue = require('vue');

import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import routes from "./routes";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    router: new VueRouter(routes),
});
```

This is my routes.js

```
import Home from './components/Home';

export default{
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: Home
    }
  ]
}
```

my Home.vue

```
<template>
    <div>HELLO WORLD, NICE VUE</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {}
</script>
```

my welcome.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

<router-view></router-view>

@endsection
```

my package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.20.1",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-loader": "^15.9.6",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "tailwindcss": "^2.0.3",
        "vue-router": "^3.5.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check browser code.......getting any error?.........<router-view></router-view>
 code should be vue file....try to check tutorial once again

Comment: It did give me a 'app.js:1892 Uncaught TypeError: Vue.use is not a function' error, I have imported view a second time using import which seems to have stopped this error.